# String to Integer not defining properly

Tags: javascript, variables, parseint

I've got a script which takes user input from a HTML form, and then defines some js variables, but the variables don't seem to be defining when I try to turn the "minute" and "hour" strings into integers.

I have the script output the variables into the console after the user inputs them, and that's working fine, but after I try to turn them into integers and output them into the console again, I just receive the "undefined" message.

```
//this is where the variables are output as strings -- this works
console.log(dropHour);
console.log(dropMinute);

//set hour and minute strings to integers -- doesn't work?
var Hour = parseInt(dropHour);
var Minute = parseInt(dropMinute);
console.log(dropMinute.type);
console.log(dropHour.type);
```

Or is there a better way to do this? Like have the input as numbers only and be a string from the get-go? I basically just need the user to be able to select a time and then have a function check that the user selected time is the same as the current time (which is done using this function, which doesn't work because of my above issue, i presume)

```
//checks if time set = current time
function checkTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    console.log(currentTime.getHours);
    if ((currentTime.getHours == Hour) && (currentTime.getMinutes == Minute)) {
        console.log("time set = time now");
        console.log(currentTime.getHours + currentTime.getMinutes);
        setInterval(otherFunction(), 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting undefined because strings do not have a `.type` property. Did you mean to do `console.log(Hour)`, `console.log(Minute)`.  Also your Hour and Minute variables would need to be global for your `checkTime` function to work, and you also are calling `otherFunction` immediately instead of passing the function as an argument to `setInterval`

Comment: Or you could use `console.log(typeof dropMinute)`

Comment: @Sam Thanks! but for some reason the variables are still strings. any Idea?

Comment: `parseInt` doesn't change the value of the actual variable. It takes the value, converts it to a number, and returns it. So you have to set it to a new variable, or the same variable like this `dropMinute = parseInt(dropMinute)`

Comment: But do you actually need `dropHour` and `dropMinute` to be of type number? You're setting `Hour` and `Minute` to their `parseInt` return values (which are of type number) so maybe you should be checking the types of those instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand this code:

```
var Hour = parseInt(dropHour);
var Minute = parseInt(dropMinute);
console.log(dropMinute.type);
console.log(dropHour.type);
```

You're creating `Hour` and `Minute` which are numbers, but then looking at `dropHour` and `dropMinute` again (`parseInt` does not *change* a variable, it returns a *new* value). Not to mention `.type` isn't quite right. Code like this is probably more what you're looking for:

```
console.log(dropHour);
console.log(dropMinute);

var Hour = parseInt(dropHour, 10);
var Minute = parseInt(dropMinute, 10);
console.log(typeof Hour);
console.log(typeof Minute);
```

Here's [a working example](https://jsbin.com/mekilu/edit?js,output): https://jsbin.com/mekilu/edit?js,output

In addition to using the correct variable, I also changed `parseInt(...)` to `parseInt(..., 10)` as it's a good idea to always specify a radix, and `Hour.type` and `Minute.type` to `typeof Hour` and `typeof Minute`.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Just a lot of silly mistakes. It's working now. I hadn't caught the fact that I was logging the wrong variable afterwards, but another user previously stated 'typeof' was the correct syntax. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

**`The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).`**

parseInt only works with string but it will also work with Object if it has a **`toString`** method & that returns a **`string`** it's internally converts object to string & calling the toString method

```
var MyClass = function() {}
MyClass.prototype.toString = function() { return '1'; }

var myClass = new MyClass();
parseInt(myClass)//outputs 1
```

So if your Object doesn't returns a **`String Number`** it won't work.

So when you are using parseInt you can check if it's not a number using **`isNaN`** function.

Reference [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).